# Uget: download time is one month behind

Tags: uget

This is a file added to queue on Friday 02 Apr
[image: uget download time]

As you can see the modified time is one month behind. The accessed time is correct. How do I make  uget to fix this? My version is 2.2.2.

Comment: Might that be the mod date of the .rar file?

Comment: @heynnema thanks. So how can I tell uget to set the date of files it is downloading to current date, not the file's original date?

Comment: Why would you want/need to do that?

Comment: @heynnema This is the default behavior in all of my browsers in every OS. I sort my Downloads folder by time, and I see recently downloaded files on top. But uget puts my files far away.

Comment: So in `Naulilus`, just change your sort to "Accessed" time. In `uget`, right-click on the downloaded file and select `Open Enclosing Folder` and it'll take you directly to the downloaded file.